# Android: retrieve html of website certain time after request

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

My goal is to retrieve the `html` of a website in a readable `String` (which I have done), and to modify the code slightly so that the `html` is retrieved a certain time after the `Get` command is made.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do: on the website http://time.gov/HTML5/, the `html` that appears right when the page loads is not the full `html`; after a few seconds, `javascript` commands execute that slightly modify the `html`. My goal is to get the modified `html`.

Here is what I have done to get the website `html`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://time.gov/HTML5/");

    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            HttpResponse response = null;
            HttpGet httpGet = null;
            HttpClient mHttpClient = null;
            String s = "";

            try {
                if(mHttpClient == null){
                    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                }


                httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);


                response = mHttpClient.execute(httpGet);
                s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            final TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headline);
            textview1.setText(result);

        }
    }
}
```

This code correctly gets the unmodified `html`. However, I am trying to get the `html` a couple seconds after the request is made (which will hopefully give it enough time to update the `html`) by using `Thread.sleep(5000)`, but this is not working. Does anyone know how to approach this problem?

Comment: Try using handler for delay.

Comment: @user3616949, when you used Traceview or other tools to determine where your time is being spent, what did you learn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I understand from your question is, you need to fetch the HTML of a web page after the page is completely loaded (After running all the scripts inside the page).

AFAIK, you cannot achieve this with your current implementation. Once you call the function `HttpClient.execute()` you cannot apply any delay within that function, it'll just fetch the currently available data. And you cannot use a `Handler` either. It'll only help you to delay the 'execute()' call.

Unfortunately we cannot set any listeners to the client which will provide a callback whenever the data in the webpage changes (At least I'm not aware of any such functionality).

But you can achieve this using a completely different yet painless method. This is how you can implement it.

1. Place a `WebView` in your activity, keep it hidden
2. Load the web page in the WebView
3. Hook the `onPageFinished()` of your `WebViewClient` implementation and From there inject the html content of the WebView in to your `JavaScriptInterface` implementation.

**The WebView:**

In your layout XML

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/my_web"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

In your Activity onCreate()

```
TextView textview1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* Your code here */

    textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

    WebView web = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_web);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.addJavascriptInterface(new CustomJavaScriptInterface(), "JavaScriptInterface");
    web.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    web.loadUrl("http://time.gov/HTML5/");

    /* Your code here */
}
```

**WebViewClient**

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //Inject the HTML in to the JavaScriptInterface
        view.loadUrl("javascript:window.JavaScriptInterface.html('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
    }
}
```

**JavaScritpInterface**

```
private class CustomJavaScriptInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void html(final String html) {
        //Your HTML is here
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setTextHtml(html);
            }
        });
        Log.e("HTML Length", Integer.toString(html.length()));
    }
}

private void setTextHtml(String html) {
    textview1.setText(html);
}
```

**Conclusion:**

To verify this, I put the line `Log.e("HTML Length", Integer.toString(html.length()));` in your AsyncTask's `postExecute()` and this is what I got logged.

> 08-05 14:29:59.886  13332-13332/com.sample.fetchhtml E/HTML Length﹕
>   10438

At the same time the log written from the function `html()` of `JavaScriptInterface` is

> 08-05 14:30:09.021  13332-13420/com.sample.fetchhtml E/HTML Length﹕
>   22498

You can see the difference in size of the HTML string I got in both cases. Hope this helps.

**Update (07 Aug):** The delay in execution depends on the time taken by the webpage to get loaded completely in the webview. This approach is suitable for webpages contains startup scripts. For a static webpage it's better to use `HttpClient.execute()`.

Comment: Cool, one quick question: which `String` contains the actual `html`? For example, if I wanted to set the text of a `TextView` as the `html`, I would go `textview.setText(___)`

Comment: The `String` parameter of function `public void html(String html)` in `CustomJavaScriptInterface` will have the actual html.

Comment: So would I go `textview.setText(html)`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do long sleeps on an AsyncTask, because it will hold up any other AsyncTask.  I would set a timer for 5 seconds and launch a second AsyncTask instance to do the second read.

Comment: So would I set a 5 second timer and then do another `task.execute("http://time.gov/HTML5/");`? Would this do a second read (which would work great) or would this do another request+read (which would give me the same result)?